# What is the preferred STL collection when that's all you need?

Tags: c++, stl

I just need a "bag of things". It doesn't need to be a set, a map or even have any particular order. I just need to be able to add things and  iterate over it, nothing more. I don't expect it to be very large but it can't get really bad perf if it does.

*What container should I use?*

Comment: A few questions: (1) Do you need to store the same value more than once?  (2) Do you need to preserve any sort of order on the elements? (3) Is _thing_ a value type?  (4) does addition need to be fast?  (5) does removal need to be fast?  I think that the answer to (2) is _no_ but I want to make sure.

Comment: @D.Shawley, #1&2: already addressed (no and no) #3 yes, #4 within reason, #5 individual removal is not needed, bulk clearing is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard recommends using vector as your default container.  But [Herb Sutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter) actually [makes a case for using deque as your first choice](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm).

Comment: +1 for the link. I believed I remembered Sutter prefering the vector, but your link cleared all that : Standard goes for vector by default, and Sutter goes for Deque by default.

Comment: Check Neil's blog about it: http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/letter-the-fourth/ . Unless you need C-compatibility, `deque` is the one-fits-them-all component.

Comment: +1 ... I was trying to remember who recommended `deque` as a good default choice

Answer (score 5):

`vector` probably has the lowest overhead of all the containers.  As long as you are not adding or removing things in the middle.

Comment: For what usage profile? </rhetorical> I guess that leads to the question of if someone has tool that estimates the overhead of using each collection type for an assumed profile of adds/iterates/removes/etc.

Comment: Vector's only weakness is middle insertion and removal, so if you don't care about anything other than that the elements are in a container, you can always just add to the end and avoid that pathological case.

Comment: I don't know about that ... `push_back()` isn't exactly what I would call _fast_ as the collection becomes large.

Comment: `push_back()` is supposed to run in constant amortized time.  That means that some calls may cause large allocations and take a long time, but the average time is constant.  This does not take into problems with paging and virtual memory, but any collection will suffer from those, and sooner than vector.

Comment: The problem with `std::vector` and `push_back()` is that the amount of contiguous space required increases as the number of elements grows.  Since `std::allocator` does not expose a resize, the implementation is forced to allocate a larger chunk, copy construct each element in turn, and then deallocate the current chunk.  This causes problems with memory fragmentation due to the shuffle on every resize and performance hits when you have a non-trivial copy constructor.

Answer (score 5):

**By default, use a vector... But then, if possible, don't forget to use a type indirection!**

The reason for that is that if you only need to iterate, then you should be able to use any one of the available STL containers, and choose it once through a typedef indirection.

For example, let's say you'll initially choose a vector (which is the default choice) :

```
typedef std::vector<MyThing> MyThingContainer ;
```

And then use the container as usual :

```
void foo(MyThingContainer & things)
{
    for(MyThingContainer::iterator it = things.begin(),
        itEnd = things.end() ;
        it != itEnd ;
        ++it)
   {
      MyThing & thing = *it ;
      // Do something with that thing
   }
}
```

This way, the day you find a list, or a deque, or whatever is a better container than a vector, just by changing the typedef and recompiling, you'll change the true type of the container.

Comment: @Fred Larson: Fact is, this is the only reason I answered. After all, all the answers were already quite enough (your answers made me pause, though), so there was no need to add another one, but for this indirection thing... ^_^ ...

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector`.  Doesn't require an `operator<`.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector is a good default choice.  It's a simple data structure, implemented as a dynamic array.  The elements are packed next to each other which is good locality of reference (beneficial for caching)